# Automatically Display the First Word of Every Quotation in Small Caps

Tags: macros, automation, small-caps

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}
\newcommand{\emdash}{\nobreak---\nobreak\hskip0pt}

\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent{#1}\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\fancyquote{{\scshape{Baseball}} is 90 percent mental. The other half is physical.}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{If people don't want to come to the ballpark, how are you going to stop them?}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{You can observe a lot by watching.}{Yogi Berra}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I automatically display the first word of every quote in small caps without having to resort to something `{\scshape{Baseball}` every time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isolate the first word with a delimited argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{\makebox[1em][s]{---\hss---}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \fancyquote@#1\@nil{#2}%
}
\def\fancyquote@#1 #2\@nil#3{%
  \par\noindent\textsc{#1} #2\\*\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash{\itshape\bfseries#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\fancyquote{Baseball is 90 percent mental. The other half is physical.}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{If people don't want to come to the ballpark, how are you going to stop them?}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{You can observe a lot by watching.}{Yogi Berra}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your first `\fancyquote` doesn't reset the font afterward, so your subsequent text is still in the cmss family. I think this was unintentional, so I changed that in my solution.

My solution works in plain TeX, it simply delimits the parameter in a TeX macro with a space.

[image: baseball quotes]

```latex
\font\twelverm=cmr10 at 12pt
\font\twelvesc=cmcsc10 at 12pt % Roman small caps
\font\twelveecso=ecso1200 % cmss bold italic
\font\twelveecss=ecss1200 % cmss default

\twelverm % Also set math fonts to 12pt here

\def\fancyquoteA#1 {{\twelvesc#1} }
\def\fancyquote#1#2{\par\noindent\fancyquoteA#1 \par\hfill{\twelveecss---\twelveecso#2}\par}

\fancyquote{Baseball is 90 percent mental. The other half is physical.}{Yogi Berra}

\vskip20pt
\fancyquote{If people don't want to come to the ballpark, how are you going to stop them?}{Yogi Berra}

\vskip20pt
\fancyquote{You can observe a lot by watching.}{Yogi Berra}

\bye
```

This can easily be converted to more LaTeX code, you can remove the `\font` definitions and replace them with LaTeX font macros instead.

Comment: I think the OP really does want the quotation text to be rendered in a sans serif font (e.g., Cabin), in addition to the first word of the quotation being rendered in small caps (and sans serif).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It makes use of Lua's built-in string function to identify the "word" -- taken to be a sequence of one or more alphabetical characters -- at the start of a string and to render this word in small caps. (Whitespace at the very start of the string *is* permitted, in the sense that it is removed from the string.) If the string of interest doesn't start with a word as defined above, the string is output without modification.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
function first_word_sc ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "^%s*(%a+)" , "\\textsc{%1}" )
  tex.sprint ( s )
end
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: utility macro that invokes the Lua function
\newcommand\FirstWordSC[1]{%
  \directlua { first_word_sc ( "#1" ) }}


\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
%\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\newfontfamily{\Cabin}{Cabin Regular}

\newcommand{\longemdash}{\textsf{\textemdash}}

\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \par\noindent{\Cabin\FirstWordSC{#1}}\\*%
  \hspace*{\fill}\longemdash\textsf{\textit{\textbf{#2}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\fancyquote{Baseball is 90 percent mental. The other half is physical.}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{If people don't want to come to the ballpark, how are you going to stop them?}{Yogi Berra}

\vspace*{20pt}

\fancyquote{  You can observe a lot by watching.}{Yogi Berra}

\end{document}
```